# Recommendation for Embedded DB with External ODBC Access?

Tags: java, database, windows, database-connection, adodb

Is there a database that can be embedded in a Java program but also allow access through ODBC; more specifically, ODBC through ADOdb?

The environment is MS Windows (XP on).

The situation is that a Java program (mine) runs an external program (not mine) that uses an ADOdb.Connection object to connect to the embedded database and extract data.  Oh, legacy support.

I've been trying to set this up using Derby (i.e. JavaDB/Cloudscape) and the NetworkServerControl object, but cannot figure out how to configure the System DSN such that an ADODB.Connection object can connect.  Chances are I'm doing it wrong, but I can't figure out how to specify the path to the Derby files.

Is there an embedded db that can be accessed in this manner?  Preferably one (unlike Derby) that doesn't require unsupported third-party drivers for ODBC access?

Alternatively, am I going about this completely wrong?  I'm not very conversant with databases, nor ADOdb or .NET in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) stated a ODBC driver on the features list (but still experimental).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I'm checking to see if H2 is what I'm looking for, in which case I'll accept this answer.  Thanks for your patience and your answer! :)