# Relation between access database and h2 database

Tags: database, csv, h2

I am looking for a way to create an automatic way that can access database and can relate to an h2 file and check against data from a special table.

What I achieved is to export data via `csv` file and import this `csv` data in access.
But I want to achieve this in an automatic way.
The background: currently 2 access databases exist and relates to each other for the data it needs to check against (3 data from a special table)

One access database is changing to h2 so the access database needs to relate to h2 files

I want to get access to read the h2 file and check against the data.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8496668/900626) h2 can use a PostgreSQL ODBC driver.  If so, Access can use linked tables via ODBC.